# How to increment a bash variable (resulting from a command) inside a for loop

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I know that there are a lot of solutions on how to increment a variable inside a loop, but I'd like to know how to increment a variable which is a already a result from a command.
Suppose I have files: `test1 test2 test3 test4`.
My command is the following:

`for i in {1..4}; do x$i=$(wc -l < test$i); done`

I get:

`x1=10: command not found`

`x2=9: command not found`

`x3=9: command not found`

`x4=9: command not found`

which command could not be found? `wc -l`?

I guess the problem is related with the position of `$`symbol

Comment: The command not found is the one before the colon.  So, `x1=10`, for example.  This doesn't solve your problem, so this is just a comment for your future reference in command line or script debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `declare` built-in for this:

```
for i in {1..4}; do declare x$i=$(wc -l < test$i); done
```